# How to use a list in a if statement

Tags: python

I was trying to make a simple If statement with a list but it doesn't work when I input one of the foods in the list, is there something I'm missing or is there a different way to do it, I'm pretty new so I don't really know a lot.
Thanks :)

```
def main():
  food = ["French Fries","Nutella","Smoothies","Macaroni","Fish Sticks"]
  ask = input("What is your favorite food?")
  num=["1.","2.","3.","4.","5."]
  if(ask == food):
    print("Cool! I also like "+ask+" alot!")
  print("These are my top 5 favorite Foods:")
  for n in range(0, len(food)):
    print(num[n]+food[n])  
        
main()
```

Comment: `if ask in food` to check for membership

Comment: `if ask in food:...`

Comment: `if(ask == food)` One of those is a String and the other is a list, they can never be equal. You have to check if your String is IN the list.

Answer (score 0):

- `ask == food` you are comparing a string with an entire list
- instead you need to check if `ask` exists inside the list

  ```
   if ask in food:
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Your line -  if(ask == food):
seems illogical. Check the list comparison syntax in python, its pretty basic. You can't compare list like this. Use in operator instead.